# Using Onsen UI, how to transition between pages using a Fade?

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, onsen-ui

In Onsen UI ( http://onsenui.io/ ) the default transition for ons.screen.presentPage consists in a page moving from the bottom to the top. 
I have a special case where, just for one of the pages, I need the new page to appear with a Fade In.
How can I change the default transition of presentPage for only one of the pages?

```
<!-- connect.html should fade in after a click on the button -->
<ons-button ng-click="ons.screen.presentPage('connect.html')">
    Next
</ons-button>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like you'll have to modify your JS a bit.

Answer (score 1):

That's not in 1.0 but we have it in the roadmap and the api would be ons.screen.presentPage( url, { animation: 'fade' }